# GCP GCS Oauth grant type

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, jwt, google-cloud-storage

I have a tool where I need to setup a flow that upload a file to GCS (granting rights to a service account).

Problem of the tool is that it's an UI and only support a "Oauth 2.0 Grants type Flow".
It asks for:

- `Authorization Server URL`
- `clientId`
- `client Secret`

It doesn't seems possible to have an authentication by a service account with only these 3 parameters: `Authorization Server URL`, `clientId` and a `client Secret`

Problem of this application is that it can't use code. Otherwise I would have used Python and do it easily.

From what I understand of Oauth2 in GCP for a service account:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization

We need to generate a JWT token by doing some signing with base64 and sha256. This is not a possible solution because the app can't use code or such algorithms.

I have the same problem with interoperability system and HMAC keys: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/aws-simple-migration

which requires a signature: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures

It seems that the task is impossible unless I missed something.

Thanks for any help !

Comment: To interact with Google API, you need an access token. But yes, you have to generate it and then use it with your tool.

Comment: if you resolve your issue @tdebroc, you can post your answer to help other communities.

Answer (score 1):

Since your software has a UI and it's asking for url/cliendID/secret there is a good chance that it will perform the token generation for you using the oauth2 protocol.

Try with the following:

Url -> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

ClientID -> your service account email

Secret -> your service account key secret (you have to generate a key in JSON format from the GCP Console UI by selecting the service account)

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. I got a  `{"error": "unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description": "Invalid grant_type"}`   .
I tried something like :
`curl -X POST -d @data-sercice-account-secret.json "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Accept: application/json"`

I'm bit lost. I kind of understand that with a service account it's not possible to do a client_crendential auth and only Oauth2 consent screen, but I would like a confirmation ...

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't notice it was an oauth2... Oauth2 is to delegate user access to an application, service accounts are not regular users that authenticate with password